# Amazon S3: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using [React-S3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3) to upload some files to S3.

and even though I have my CORS configured

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>9000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

it still Access-Control-Allow-Origin error whenever I'm trying to upload to S3.

Comment: are you running this on localhost?

Comment: @RandallHunt yes.

Comment: Try accessing the webpage through http://lvh.me (which resolves ro 127.0.0.1) or another host that resolves to loclahost and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding POST as an AllowedMethod as well. This will allow browser-based uploads. More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

Comment: hey @bwest, I did add POST to it but now it gives me this error instead: - POST https://*url*.s3.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request), any idea how to fix it? :)